# Parabolic satellite dish

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

If the axis of paraboloid z=(x^2+y^2)/2 is tilted by 30 degrees anticlockwise then what will be the equation of the plane formed by water level inside it. The water level will surely be parellel to x and y axis. It will be z= something constant. If  I am wrong then please correct it. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it will be parallel to the $xy$-plane, and have equation $z=k$.

Comment: I am new to this. What is that dollar sign?

Comment: Any idea of the plane. It will be elliptical. But how to find it?

Comment: LaTeX is a well known piece of software that lets you type maths. This site takes LaTeX code. If you put things between dollar signs then it converts that in to maths. You can write things like x^2+4x+1 to get $x^2+4x+1$. You can do fancy stuff like \sum to give $\sum$, and \int to get $\int$. It's hard to start, but once you get the hang of it, you can type maths as quickly as you can type words.